# Redirect https URL to another https URL for the same Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

This might be a stupid question, and for that I'm sorry, I'm not well-versed in DNS configurations (so perhaps I shouldn't be meddling in this, lol), but anyhow..

I have a web app running in Azure that is currently undergoing a bit of a name change. Therefore, I want to redirect users trying to access my domain to another domain, let's say https://example.com to https://subdomain.anotherexample.com. I own both domains and have certificates for both of them, but I cannot for the life of me understand how (or if its even possible) to redirect users in this way?

I have both URLs configured as A records for the underlying IPv4 adress, and have tried to configure a re-direct in my cPanel to redirect the domain example.com to https://subdomain.anotherexample.com, but if I try to access https://example.com it just complains that the certificate is from another provider (not my Azure certificate, but instead my web hosting certificate used for other sites). Both URLs are set up as custom domains for the same app service in Azure with SNI SSL certificate bindings where example.com is bound to a standard certificate for that specific domain, while subdomain.anotherexample.com is bound to a wildcard certificate for *.anotherexample.com.

I assume there must be something that's not allowed in trying to redirect between two different domains where https is involved because trying to access http://example.com works (i.e. it re-directs to https://subdomain.anotherexample.com). Do I have to write some kind of script server-side that re-directs users manually?